# Javascript binding issue not resolved by calling bind

Tags: javascript, binding, this

I am trying to recursively call a function until the game has ended, however, during the execution "this" gets reset to 'window', which causes the following error: "cannot read property 'step' of undefined."

I have tried rewriting the offending line as

```
this.game.bind(this).step();
```

as well as

```
this.game.step.bind(this);
```

Neither are working. For context, step is just a function that calls two helpers in Game that move objects and look for collisions, when I used those instead of step, the error remained.

```
/* globals key */
const Game = require('./game.js');
let speed = 1;


function GameView(ctx) {
  this.ctx = ctx;
  this.game = new Game();
}

GameView.prototype.start = function (callback) {
  // let that = this
  this.bindKeyHandlers();
  this.animate(0);
};

GameView.prototype.animate = function(time) {

    speed += 1;
    if (speed >= 605) {
      speed = 0;
    };

    this.game.step();
    this.game.draw(this.ctx, speed);
    if(!this.game.lose()){
      requestAnimationFrame(this.animate());
    }
    else {
    this.ctx.fillStyle = "white";
    this.ctx.font = "italic "+24+"pt Arial ";
    this.ctx.fillText(`Game Over \n Press Enter to restart`, 100,200 );
      key('enter', ()=>{
        this.game = new Game();
        this.start();
      });
    }
};


GameView.prototype.bindKeyHandlers = function() {
  key('d', () => {
    this.game.ship.power([2, 0]);
  });
  key('a', () => {
    this.game.ship.power([-2, 0]);
  });
  key('s', () => {
    this.game.ship.power([0, 2]);
  });
  key('w', () => {
    this.game.ship.power([0, -2]);
  });
  key('l', () => {
    this.game.ship.fireBullet();
  });
};


module.exports = GameView;
```

Comment: Where is `.bind()` used at `javascript`? Should parameter passed to `requestAnimationFrame` be a reference to a function?

Comment: Are you sure that `new Game()` is generating an object?

Comment: Do you realize that `.bind()` returns a new function that you then need to call?  Neither of the examples you tried are actually calling the function that `.bind()` returns.

Comment: should be `requestAnimationFrame(this.animate.bind(this));`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your problem is that `this` of the `animate` function does not refer to the context you wish it to. So your offending line (or lack thereof) is completely elsewhere.

`Function.bind` returns a function and you need to this new bound functions somewhere and the perfect place for this is the constructor. Here's an example:

```
function GameView(ctx) {
  this.ctx = ctx;
  this.game = new Game();
  this.animate = this.animate.bind(this)
}
```

See this [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/k9no80tm/) for more, remember to open your developer console to witness the error from calling `notBound`

Hope this helps!